# Is it possible to put a background image in an amChart XY Chart only over the grid with CSS?

Tags: css, amcharts

Working on an application to plot hockey shot data, and I'm using an XY amChart to plot my data. I've been able to add a background image over the chartdiv with the following:

```
#chartdiv{
    background-image: url("/imgs/rink.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: calc(100% - 10px) calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

I've tried using `calc` to align the image perfectly between the grid lines, but it doesn't work on all displays. The above CSS yeilds the follwing results on two different screens:
[image: Rink grid on a monitor]

And:
[image: Rink grid on a laptop screen]

Note the overlap on the left side of the second image.

How can I keep the image within the grid lines?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to add transparent space to the edge of the image, so it fits when scaled at full with of the chart. That is when you always have the same % of the chart taken up by the axis with numbers.

Comment: @kajacx Is that doable with pure CSS or would that require modifying the image itself?

Comment: I mean modifying the image itself. I am no CSS expert, so that's what I would do.

Comment: If you would consider moving to amCharts 4 (you seem to be using V3), there would be a way to add a background for specifically the plot area.

Answer (score 0):

there is a property called backgroundImage in amcharts you can simply add it like

```
{
  .... amcharts configrations ....

  backgroundImage:'image.png'

  .... amcharts configrations ....
}
```

check [this](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3/blob/master/samples/barWithBackgroundImage.html) file for refrense